# Cómo insertar un DateTime NULL por medio de un form al Sql Server?

Tags: c#

Por medio de un formulario se puede ingresar una fecha y luego lo quiero insertar en la base de datos.
La cuestión es que quiero que permita ingresar fecha NULA (se deja vacio el campo en el formulario).

```
Datetime fecha = Request.Form["fecha"];

<form action="#" method="post">
        <label>Fecha Impresion:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fecha" value="" />
        <br />
</form>

db.Query("INSERT INTO Fecha VALUES(@0)", fecha);
```

Cómo puedo hacer? Ya que me tira un error de que fecha no puede ser nula y no se cómo parsearlo para que lo envie como nulo.

Comment: El problema lo tienes en la Base de datos dónde tienes que marcar que el campo puede ser NULL.

Comment: @Popplar: Para enteder bien la causa del error, es bueno incluir un [mcve]. Y sobre todo, incluir los detalles del error completos (mensaje + stack trace).

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el error que te está enviando? Con eso nos podríamos dar una idea de la razón de la falla.

Comment: Pikoh me saco la duda. El problema es que al mandar la query el valor de fecha estaba literalmente nula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el problema no es por ser nulo, si no por estar en blanco el campo fecha. Intenta usar este código:

```
db.Query("INSERT INTO Fecha VALUES(@0)", fecha=="" ? null:fecha);
```

O quizá:

```
if (fecha=="")
{
    db.Query("INSERT INTO Fecha VALUES(@0)", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
   db.Query("INSERT INTO Fecha VALUES(@0)", fecha);
}
```

No tengo ahora para probarlo :)

Comment: Gracias, era esto. Perdón por no explayar mas el código y del error que tiraba. El problema es que estaba literalmente nulo y por eso no se mandaba nada en la query.

Comment: @Popplar, por favor marca esta respuesta como la respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema no lo tienes en el código sino en la base de datos. Modifica tu tabla `fecha` para que el campo pertinente acepte el valor `NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE Fecha
ALTER COLUMN your_column Datetime NULL
```

Dónde `your_column` es el nombre de la columna en tu tabla `Fecha`

Comment: Miquel, ya lo tenía activado para que acepte NULL y sin embargo el problema sigue presente.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934621/insert-null-empty-value-in-sql-datetime-column-by-default

Siguiendo el link anterior solo necesitaras validar la fecha que envías desde el form casteando "Request.Form["fecha"]"

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría dos cambios en tu código. El primero es declarar la fecha como `Nullable`:

```
DateTime? fecha = Request.Form["fecha"];
```

El segundo, formatear la cadena para que no genere excepciones en el `query`:

```
db.Query(string.Format("INSERT INTO Fecha VALUES({0})", fecha == null ? "NULL" : fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
```